# Split up a matrix into chunks considering the values of a column in Linux

Tags: bash, awk

EDITED. I want to split up a matrix called 'matrix' into chunks based on the values in the first column, 'GENE', and save each chunk as a separate .gz file. So that, there would be subsets of the matrix, each of which will have the lines corresponding to the only 3 GENEs, just not the last one as shown in the example below. The script should be prepared in Bash.

Input:

```
> matrix
GENE Individual Expr1 Expr2 Expr3
ENSG1 indv1 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG1 indv2 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG2 indv1 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG2 indv2 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG3 indv1 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG3 indv2 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG4 indv1 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG4 indv2 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG5 indv1 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG5 indv2 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG6 indv1 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG6 indv2 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG7 indv1 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG7 indv2 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG8 indv1 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG8 indv2 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG9 indv1 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG9 indv2 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG10 indv1 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG10 indv2 0.1 0.2 0.3
```

Outputs:

```
> matrix.chunk1
GENE Individual Expr1 Expr2 Expr3
ENSG1 indv1 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG1 indv2 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG2 indv1 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG2 indv2 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG3 indv1 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG3 indv2 0.1 0.2 0.3

> matrix.chunk2
GENE Individual Expr1 Expr2 Expr3
ENSG4 indv1 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG4 indv2 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG5 indv1 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG5 indv2 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG6 indv1 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG6 indv2 0.1 0.2 0.3

> matrix.chunk3
GENE Individual Expr1 Expr2 Expr3
ENSG7 indv1 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG7 indv2 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG8 indv1 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG8 indv2 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG9 indv1 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG9 indv2 0.1 0.2 0.3

> matrix.chunk4
GENE Individual Expr1 Expr2 Expr3
ENSG10 indv1 0.1 0.2 0.3
ENSG10 indv2 0.1 0.2 0.3
```

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: you said `split up a big matrix in chunks by the unique values of the first column` but your expected output doesn't meet this, could you please clarify on same once.

Comment: I am trying to prepare the script so that it can break up the matrix into chunks. So, for each, there would be subsets of the matrix, each of which will have 100 records, just not the last one. What I mean by 'unique values' is that I think one way could be extracting the unique values of the column GENE, chunk it then use each pieces as a pattern to split up the main matrix.

Comment: Replace all the ..s in your sample input and output with real values so we can better understand your requirements. Right now it's not at all clear what you're trying to do. Obviously don't post an example that's hundreds of lines long to be split into 100 or less lines, post an example that's, say, 10 lines long to be slit into 3 or less lines.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you. I've tried to edit the question as you have suggested

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, haven't test it as of now should work though.

```
awk -v file="1" '
FNR==1{
  next
}
!b[$1]++ && ++count==100{
  close(outfile)
  file++
} 
!a[$1]++{
  outfile="mat" file
  print > (outfile)
}
' Input_file
```